# Modern looking theme for dojo?

Tags: dojo

I'm new to Dojo - exploring all docs and finding all the widgets I need for my project. I'm really impressed.

But I have one question: are there any "modern looking" themes for Dojo? Not that outlook/windows look, with less "app" and more "web" feel.

Comment: I hear you.  Claro.css and Tundra.css seem to be pretty common in the examples.  They are nice, but not super clean looking.

Comment: You can use dojo theme flat which has a "modern" looks.

More information can be found here:

https://github.com/dojo/themes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what themes you like, but the standard themes are documented [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/themes.html).
Another theme that might be useful to follow is the [Dojo bootstrap theme](http://thesociable.github.io/dbootstrap/), it is still under development but it looks nice already. It's based upon the popular Twitter Bootstrap UI toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same requirement, .. so I decided to make it myself, ..

Check [Semantic Dojo](http://websemantics.github.io/semantic-dojo/), a Dojo theme built on [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) framework. The idea is to build a Dojo theme that plays nicely with the used CSS framework (here, Semantic UI).

All the implemented Dijit widgets inherit their styles from their Semantic UI counterparts if any. Semantic Dojo uses a powerful build system based on LESS that makes building themes for Dijit widgets easy.